# How to clear Memcached (1.4.x) stats from java

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

Running flush() on the java-clients we've tried (SpyMemcacheD and Danga) does not reset the statistics on the memcached server.

Does anyone know a good way to do this? I could implement a telnet client that sends

> stats reset

But that seems excessive

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
c.getStats("reset");
```

Comment: yes, that is not an option in Danga client, and gives an exception in SpyMemcached client.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  It's the correct way to do it.  If there's a bug, file it (with a description of what went wrong).

Answer (score 0):

If you have MemcachedClient object then you can call the flush method with the help of object.  It will reset the all the value stored in MemcachedClient object the to null.